# Parse Byte Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, xml-parsing

Currently, I am inserting XML data into a byte array using the inputstream from server. My requirement is that it needs to remove a few XML nodes in the byte array. What is the best approach? Below are options I had:

1. Convert the byte array to an XML file and do the parsing using DOM or SAX.
2. Insert the data into an XML file instead of a byte array and parse using DOM and SAX parsers.

My doubt is if there is any way to remove XML nodes in a byte array like DOM and SAX parsers. Please guide me - thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can do that with DOM or sax, because both gave you abstraction in terms of nodes and strings.... vtd-xml is the only api that gives you the option to manipulate xml on byte level in java, ... in C or C++ you have also pugi-xml and rapid-xml.. I think...

Answer (score 0):

Use jdom2 library. It is the easiest to perform any edit functionality using jdom2

---

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jdom/jdom2/2.0.6

Comment: It is parse to xml data in any file.But my requirement is that my xml data stored in byte array in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your array to [ByteArrayInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) and pass the stream to `XMLInputFactory.createXMLEventReader` to create SAX parser (or to any other InputStream-consuming method).

UPD: Or better pass original inputstream ("the inputstream from server") and collect your XML filter output to byte array.

Comment: Yes!  Pass the original InputStream.  Don’t read the whole thing into memory for no reason.